# Tag synonyms: J2EE and Java-EE

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, retag-request

Enterprise Java have been named differently over the years, from [Java Platform, Enterprise Edition (Java EE) Technical Documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/) it has been named:

- Java EE 6 Documentation
- Java EE 5 Documentation
- J2EE 1.4 Documentation
- J2EE 1.3 Documentation
- J2EE 1.2.1 Documentation

Yes, it looks like J2EE has changed name to Java EE. On stackoverflow, two different tags are used `j2ee` and `java-ee`, both has been used around 2000 times. I suggest that one should be a tag-synonym to the other. In fact `java-ee` is already added as a [synonym to `j2ee`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/j2ee/synonyms) - but it has only one vote. I think more people vote on it if it gets more attention.

But since the name has changed from J2EE to Java EE it would be better to use the tag `java-ee` and add `j2ee` as a sysnonym to it. But the problem here is that only moderators can add the j2ee-tag as sysnonym since "Version specific synonyms can only be created by moderators".

In summary, I suggest that:

- `java-ee` and `j2ee` should be tag synonyms
- The name `java-ee` should be used instead of `j2ee`

Comment: There is a similar issue with `j2se`, which should be a synonym of [java-se](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/synonyms).

Comment: I have downvoted the java-ee synonym on j2ee. I don't want that all java-ee tags becomes j2ee. It should not happen or at least be the other way round.

Comment: @Chichiray: That is what I wrote here: the tag should be named `java-ee` and not `j2ee`.

Comment: @mcdowell see my answer

Comment: @Chichiray: do you have any input to @Jeff:s answer?

Comment: I personally don't agree with the synonym/retag at all. "j2ee" is basically a version tag which applies J2EE 1.2-1.4 only. There are also "java-ee-5" and "java-ee-6" tags. If we continue this way, we should also merge/synonymize them to "java-ee". And then do the same for "ejb", "jsf", "struts", "jpa", "c#", ".net", "asp.net", "internet-explorer" and all thousand other tags which have version-tags...

Comment: @Chichiray: Ok, I see `j2ee` and `java-ee` as tags for "Java Platform, Enterprise Edition" as decribed above. If it should be a tag for each version then it should have been `j2ee-1.4`, `j2ee-1.3` added to the tags `java-ee-5` and `java-ee-6`, in my point of view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The synonym was reversed and approved.

Do you want all the old [j2ee](/questions/tagged/j2ee) questions *renamed* to [java-ee](/questions/tagged/java-ee) ?

As for [j2se](/questions/tagged/j2se) the synonym [java-se](/questions/tagged/java-se) already remaps to [java](/questions/tagged/java), is this correct?

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms

Comment: Great that `j2ee` now is synonym to `java-ee`! Yes, I think it would be good if the old `j2ee` is renamed to `java-ee` so they are grouped together. Yes, it's correct that `java-se` maps to `java` and it would be good if `j2se` also is a synonym to `java` (and renamed).

Comment: Whether j2se/java-se/javase should be synonymous with the java tag is a grey area; java-se is more specific and other platforms (ME/EE/Android/etc.) are  intersecting sets of functionality. A lot of stuff tagged java is not java-se.

Comment: @mcdowell I don't know Java well enough to make decisions on such subtleties; perhaps open another meta Q about this?

Comment: Good branding control is why [by installing Java, you will be able to experience the power of Java](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2009/01/12.html). The question is here: [Should tags java-se/javase/j2se be synonyms of java?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91401).

Comment: If it factors into your thinking about renaming tags, I expect that some people will be referring to Java EE as J2EE at least until the heat death of the universe and will tag/search accordingly.