# Should tags java-se/javase/j2se be synonyms of java?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

As part of [the cleanup on Java-EE tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90917/tag-synonyms-j2ee-and-java-ee), the question of whether all things [Java Standard Edition](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/index.html) should be synonymous with the [java](/questions/tagged/java) tag. [java-se](/questions/tagged/java-se), and [javase](/questions/tagged/javase), currently are; [j2se](/questions/tagged/j2se),.

So, should tags [java-se](/questions/tagged/java-se)/[javase](/questions/tagged/javase),/[j2se](/questions/tagged/j2se) be synonyms of [java](/questions/tagged/java)?

There is a lot of stuff tagged [java](/questions/tagged/java) on SO; much of it is for Android, Java EE, Java ME, etc. - platforms that are intersecting sets of functionality with Java SE.

Comment: There's [a feature request for putting tags "on hold"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107754/put-tag-on-hold) that was generated to address this issue (well, for VB-related tags, but it works just as well for Java).

Answer (score 8):

My opinion is that `java-se`, `javase`, and `j2se` ought to be synonyms, but not synonyms of `java`.

Java is the whole collection, of which Java SE is but a part.  As you say, "there is a lot of stuff tagged `java` on SO; much of it is for Android, Java EE, Java ME, etc. - platforms that are intersecting sets of functionality with Java SE."

Answer (score 2):

Yes. I'd rather not have to "ignore tag" *all* of them.

[java-se](/questions/tagged/java-se), [javase](/questions/tagged/javase), and [j2se](/questions/tagged/j2se) should be grouped together, at the very least.

They are a "subset" of [java](/questions/tagged/java), so I'm not sure if we should make them synonymous to [java](/questions/tagged/java) in addition.

Comment: just in case you're not aware of it - you can [filter tags on wildcards](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69230).

Comment: @McDowell Thanks! I didn't know about it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `java-se`, `javase`, and `j2se`, etc. should be synonyms of `java`.

SE is the standard platform and what most people associate with the term Java.

<sub>I thought I'd add this answer for those who argue to keep the status quo; I wasn't sure if the question upvotes votes indicate support for the question or not.</sub>