# Semi-blacklist tags (put tags on hold)

Tags: feature-request, blocked-tags

Currently burninated (non-blacklisted) tags can just come back (do they?).

I personally don't think most [1500 reputation users](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) have enough experience on the site to know when to recreate tags we've previously decided should be burninated.

I suggest we implement some functionality to allow high-reputation users to vote to semi-blacklist a tag (let's call it to put it "on hold") and to vote to reactivate it (approved on +5 score for each?, declined on -5?). Perhaps we can have a separate list for declined ones, so they can get voted on if there is disagreement.

Let's say 'high-reputation' is 20k+ reputation (or 10k+?).

A screen similar to [tag synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms) seems like a good idea:

[image]

The difference between 'gone' and 'on hold' (I think) is an important one - when 'on hold', there are still questions with the tag (can serve as an indicator of questions that need cleaning up), 'gone' means the tag is ... gone.

A tag being put **on hold doesn't remove it from all the questions containing the tag.** Once a tag is on hold, **it simply can't be *added* to questions**.

And perhaps when a high-reputation user tries to reactivate a semi-blacklisted tag, **a message** will be displayed.

> The [homework-lol] tag is currently on hold. If you feel this tag should be reactivated, please vote to do so on [the tag blacklist page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/blacklist)

(possibly not the best link, as [blacklist](/questions/tagged/blacklist) is currently a tag).

I also think preventing a tag from being added to new questions will be great for these tags with a large amount of questions that needs to be burninated (and just in general) - new questions with the tag keep coming, thus that makes it so much more work to get rid of it.

If it's not a good idea to put this power in the community's hands (i.e. probably the same reason only the dev team can currently blacklist tags), can someone explain why?

Perhaps the devs / mods can just get involved if a tag keeps getting put on hold and reactivated.

Perhaps we should also **add a link to it on [the review page](https://stackoverflow.com/review)** for visibility (or somewhere else?).

This should get rid of most burninate and blacklist requests on Meta.

This is similar to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107754/put-tag-on-hold) (and I'm sure some others), but this request is a lot more specific.

Comment: Dupe with less information: [Put Tag on hold](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107754/put-tag-on-hold).

Comment: Highly related/possible dupe: [Add the ability to “lock” tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151920/add-the-ability-to-lock-tags/151925#151925)